# Как печатать timedelta без долей секунд

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
doc = pd.read_csv('document.csv', sep=';', encoding='cp1251')
service_type = doc['Услуга']

for i in service_type.unique():
    fltr = doc.loc[service_type == i]
    fltr['Время выполнения'] = pd.to_timedelta(fltr['Время выполнения'])
    summ = fltr['Время выполнения'].sum()
    if len(fltr['Время выполнения']) > 0:
        final = summ/len(fltr['Время выполнения'])
        print(i+":", '\n', final)
```

на выходе имеем числа формата

```
days 04:49:51.200000
0 days 11:04:20.833333333
0 days 00:36:24
и т.д.
```

Как можно избавиться от чисел после точки?

Comment: [Округлить](https://pythonchik.ru/matematika/okruglenie-v-python)? [Вывести с заданной точностью](https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/cing.Libs.io/-/fprintf/python-fprintf-function-examples.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у pandas.timedelta есть [метод](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.round.html#pandas.Timedelta.round) round, а то, что делает ваш код, можно сделать с помощью группировки без цикла, примерно так:

```
doc['Время выполнения'] = pd.to_timedelta(doc['Время выполнения'])
res = doc.groupby('Услуга')['Время выполнения'].mean().round('s').reset_index()

# получите дата фрейм такого вида
print(res)
'''
  Услуга Время выполнения
0      a  0 days 12:50:12
1      b  0 days 15:20:12
2      c  0 days 17:50:06
```

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант - создаете новый объект `timedelta`, в котором количество секунд округляете до целого:

```
from datetime import timedelta

td = timedelta(seconds=123456.789)
print(td)  # 1 day, 10:17:36.789000

td2 = timedelta(seconds=int(td.total_seconds()))
print(td2)  # 1 day, 10:17:36
```

Другой вариант - в [исходниках класса `timedelta`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/129998bd7b133defa37c7529bfad9052c0022b5c/Lib/datetime.py#L573) смотрите [метод `__str__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/129998bd7b133defa37c7529bfad9052c0022b5c/Lib/datetime.py#L707), создаете на его основе свою функцию форматирования:

```
# def __str__(self):
#     mm, ss = divmod(self._seconds, 60)
#     hh, mm = divmod(mm, 60)
#     s = "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hh, mm, ss)
#     if self._days:
#         def plural(n):
#             return n, abs(n) != 1 and "s" or ""
#         s = ("%d day%s, " % plural(self._days)) + s
#     if self._microseconds:
#         s = s + ".%06d" % self._microseconds
#     return s

def format_timedelta(td: timedelta):
    mm, ss = divmod(td.seconds, 60)
    hh, mm = divmod(mm, 60)
    s = "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hh, mm, ss)
    if td.days:
        def plural(n):
            return n, abs(n) != 1 and "s" or ""
        s = ("%d day%s, " % plural(td.days)) + s
    # убираем отображение микросекунд
    return s

print(format_timedelta(timedelta(seconds=123456.789))) # 1 day, 10:17:36
```